# Problem top menu active

Tags: css, menu

In my web site http://www.chocolate-shop.it

I have a problem with active menu top.

If I enter in web site, go out and re-enter some the menu items remain active.

Comment: Please search the logs for some errors, make the issue reproducible for us. Without further information we have no way to help you with the issue

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to css.